# Is there a iOS player app that display composer id3 info and play Apple Music songs?

Tags: ios, apple-music, music.app

The current (iOS 9.2.1) Music iOS app doesn't seem to show the current played song's composer name. I need an app that show that information, and which work playing Apple music songs. Is there any?

Answer (score 1):

You can try MyAudioStream audio application for iPhone and iPod. A nice music player and audio streamer to playback or beam music that you have stored on PC, MAC any UPnP/DLNA server wirelessly and transfer to any wireless speakers, AV receivers. I have at home PC with Serviio installed, like a server and stream the songs to my device from there wirelessly.

Comment: While it doesn't do what I need, I will install it on a relative's device. Thank you.